# I cannot redirect thre page by using phantomjs

Tags: phantomjs

I cannot redirect the page by using  phantomjs
The page redirect to login page when i am trying to change the current page location to other of the same web [age by using phantomjs

Comment: Please add the code and URLs for your issue. Currently it is not clear at all what you're asking.

Comment: i am using phantom js for automation , when i am click on a link the new page is opening on another tab. So my problems is that i can't redirect to that location..,

Comment: Redirecting at the login time may go wrong, without the `--cookies-file` option.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the current object value as new page instead of redirecting
    newPage=page.pages[0];

Comment: That's interesting! Add more details / some code into answer.